# Structure initialization as argument

Tags: c++, list, structure, initializing

I try to send some struct into STL list;

```
struct obj {
  int a;
  int b;
}

list < struct obj> mylist;

struct obj a  = { 0, 1}; 
mylist.push_back ( a);
```

Is there any other way to initialize argument of `push_back`?
For example:

```
mylist.push_back ( struct obj a ={0, 1});
```

g++ tells me: expected primary-expression before "struct";

Comment: Why don't you write a constructor? If for some reason you feel you cannot, write a named constructor: `obj make_obj(...)`.

Comment: Already got some good answers.  As an aside - unlike in C, there's no need to keep repeating "struct obj" after you've declared it... C++ works with just `list<obj>`, `obj a`.

Answer (score 3):

Define a constructor on `struct obj`:

```
obj::obj(int a, int b) // : initializers
{
 // Implementation
}
```

Use

```
int val1, val2;
mylist.push_back(obj(val1, val2));
```

C++0x has [new ways to initialize inline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Initializer_lists). I have seen statements including from [Stroustrup](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#init-list) that STL containers can be initialized using `std::initializer_list<T>` in which case it would look something like this in your case where `T` is `obj`.

```
std::list mylist({obj(val1, val2), obj(val3, val4)});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you give your struct a constructor with a and b as parameters? If you use initializer lists, this should be as fast as your old code and you can say

```
mylist.push_back(obj(a,b));
```